# On PHP, how to exit or quit form "php -r '<something>'" when ">" keeps appearing in the terminal?

Tags: php, terminal, console

### I'm trapped by `php -r` and can't escape from the "`>`".

---

I tried to run a simple PHP command from the terminal. Which was `$ php -r '<the PHP commands>'`, so to see what the results would be.

But **something went wrong and the terminal keeps showing me the "`>`" console**. Whatever I type gives me nothing but "`>`". Even `^C` (control+C) nor Command+`q` didn't exit/escape/quit from the situation.

The commands supposed to be something like so:

```php
php -r '$url_img_source="[here URL]"; echo serialize(file_get_contents($url_img_source));'
```

Since the URL was too long to type, after typing `php -r '$url_img_source=`, I copied and pasted it.

But 2 things I failed.

1. The copied string was **quoted with a single quotation instead of double**.
2. The copied string contained a **line break (Enter) at the end**.

Therefore, as soon as I pasted it, it started to run. Before finishing the script. I always do things like this and this time I've been trapped ...

```
$ php -r '$url_img_source='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%80%E3%82%B9_%E4%BB%AE%E9%9D%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0_%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%98%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3_%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B4%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84_%28%E3%82%B4%E3%83%BC%E2%98%86%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B9%29_22m30s.jpg';

>
> q
> quit
> quit()
> exit
> exit()
> ^C
> bye
>
>
> die
> die()
> :q
>
```

I sent a `reset` and `hard reset` signal from the terminal too but didn't work. Just cleared the screen and again the "`>`" showed up.

I could turn down the terminal window. But since I'm running this on Docker PHP7-alpine container over macOS Mojave, and there are other files that haven't saved to local so I am afraid to shut the terminal down by force.

What other choices do I have?

Comment: Your quotes in your second block do not match the quotes in the first block. It's doing the `>` for the command line because it's expecting another single `'` to finish the statement. Hitting  ctrl-c or  ctrl-d should get you back out of it

Comment: Did you try typing a single quote ?

Comment: @aynber ctrl-c didn't work but ctrl-d did work! Thanks!

Comment: @Cid Also typing a single quote did work!! Thank you both. I will answer the question asap I finish saving the data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 3 things you should try to escape from "`>`"

1. Try `'` and return/enter ([@cid's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303960/on-php-how-to-exit-or-quit-form-php-r-something-when-keeps-appearing?noredirect=1#comment102970288_58303960))

```
   $ php -r '$url_img_source='https://upload.wikimedia.org/...%22m30s.jpg';

   > '

   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in Command line code on line 1
   $
```

2. Try `ctrl-d` ([@aynber's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303960/on-php-how-to-exit-or-quit-form-php-r-something-when-keeps-appearing?noredirect=1#comment102970266_58303960))

```
   $ php -r '$url_img_source='https://upload.wikimedia.org/...%22m30s.jpg';

   > /bin/sh: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
   $
```

3. Try `↑` up arrow key to roll back the history and select the same command and run.

```
   $ php -r '$url_img_source='https://upload.wikimedia.org/...%22m30s.jpg';

   > php -r '$url_img_source='https://upload.wikimedia.org/...%22m30s.jpg';

   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in Command line code on line 1
   $
```

Answer (score 2):

```
php -r '$url_img_source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%80%E3%82%B9_%E4%BB%AE%E9%9D%A2%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0_%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%98%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3_%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%B4%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84_%28%E3%82%B4%E3%83%BC%E2%98%86%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%82%B9%29_22m30s.jpg";';
```

You are missing the double quotes in your example.

Look, you have: `php -r '$url_img_source='https://upload.wikimedi...`

It should be: `php -r '$url_img_source="..."`

Comment: He knows what caused the bug. He wants to know how to quit the php cli

Comment: Ah, well... 'Control+C' or 'Control+D' should quit the php-cli :)

Comment: @Chemaclass Thanks for the answer. As @​cid​ mentioned I just wanted to quit the PHP CLI since contrl+c didn't work for me and I panicked like a monkey. Ctrl+D worked though, thanks!